# WPF TreeView PreviewMouseDown on TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, treeview, click

If I handle the PreviewMouseDown event on TreeViewItem, I get events for everything I click on that TreeViewItem include the little +/- box to the left (Windows XP). How can I distinguish that?

I tried the following:

```
// We've had a single click on a tree view item
// Unfortunately this is the WHOLE tree item, including the +/-
// symbol to the left. The tree doesn't do a selection, so we
// have to filter this out...
MouseDevice device = e.Device as MouseDevice;

// This is bad. The whole point of WPF is for the code
// not to know what the UI has - yet here we are testing for
// it as a workaround. Sigh...

// This is broken - if you click on the +/- on a item, it shouldn't
// go on to be processed by OnTreeSingleClick... ho hum!
if (device.DirectlyOver.GetType() != typeof(Path))
{
    OnTreeSingleClick(sender);
}
```

What I'm after is just single click on the tree view item excluding the extra bits it seems to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use the SelectionItemChanged event, seems to avoid issues with the +/- button.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, `e.OriginalSource` should contain the control you *actually* clicked on. Make sure it's a TextBlock (or whatever is actually in your TreeView). You could also use something like [this post](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent) to determine which TreeViewItem the OriginalSource belongs to, if you're paranoid.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a means to detect if I've clicked on the +/- button to the left of the TreeViewItem. What I'm seeing is Border or Path. Unfortunately, if you click on a text block just outside of the text block, you get a Border. So I cannot distinguish between clicking on the TreeViewItem or the +/-. The only unique thing I'm seeing is Path - however, if I use a Path item inside a TreeViewItem, how do I tell them apart?

Comment: Perhaps set the Tag property of anything you put as the "content" of the TreeViewItem in order to distinguish it from something else?